# Prove that every non-zero element has multiplicative inverse in this set

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $\mathbb{Z}_3=\{0,1,2\}$ and addition and multiplication are in hang of 3. In other words, $\mathbb{Z}_3=\{[0],[1],[2]\}$ that its elements are equivalent classes in hang of 3.

Now let $F=\{a+bx\,|\,a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3\}$. Define addition and multiplication like polynomials. But there's one difference in multiplication. Subsitute every $x^2$ with $-1$. For example:

$(1+2x)(2+x)=2+x+x+2x^2=2+x+x-2=2x$

Show that every non-zero element in $F$ has multiplicative inverse. Actually it shows $F$ is a field of order 9.

Actually one way to show this, is to find a multiplicative inverse for each element. For example:

$([1]+[1]x)([2]+[1]x)=[2]+[1]x+[2]x+[1]x^2=[2]+[3]x-[1]=1$

Is this the correct way to show it? Or there is a more general or algebraic way to prove it?

Comment: That's a valid way of doing it, though that will require checking at least several polynomials (you can reduce some work by noting constant nonzero polynomials clearly have inverses, and any polynomial of the form $[2]x+[a]$ can be multiplied through by $[2]$ to get a monic one, so you can consider only the monic polynomials of degree $1$).

Comment: There is a more algebraic way to show it (and its generalizations) that writes that field as a quotient of the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Your brute force calculation is a good way to prepare to understand that abstract version.

Comment: The standard argument uses that $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$, so given any $a(x)$ of degree $1$, you have $x^2+1 = q(x)a(x)+r$ with $r\neq 0$ and $q(x)$ of degree $1$. Substituting $x^2$ with $-1$ gives $q(x)a(x)=-r$, with $-r$ invertible, so that will give you an inverse for $a(x)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin why $-r$ is invertible?

Comment: @JacobMartina It is a nonzero constant.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks. I thought maybe that can be a 1st deg polynomial or it should have some other condition. but it seems r is just a constant. thanks anyway

Comment: @JacobMartina $r$ is the remainder when you divide by a polynomial of degree $1$, so it must be a constant. And because $x^2+1$ is irreducible, it cannot be zero.